# regular expression: The beginning and end of the string with a letter with a specified length

Tags: c#, regex

I use this pattern but I do not get the answer. `Regex reg = new Regex(@"^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\.]*(?:[A-Za-z])){6,30}@mydomain.com$");`

I want my string to start with a letter and end with a letter, with a combination of letters, numbers, and dots, provided it is between 6 and 30 characters long.

For example: a.124b@mydomain.com or abc.1e@mydomain.com and ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    string pattern = @"^[a-z][a-z0-9.]{4,28}[a-z]@mydomain\.com$";
    string input = @"a.124b@mydomain.com";
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
    
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
    }
```

now the explanation:

- `^[a-z]` start of the string, and one letter
- `[a-z0-9.]{4,28}` letters, digits and dot character (you don't need to escape it when in square brackets), repeated between 4 and 28 times
- `[a-z]` another single letter
- (those in combination amont to 6 to 30 characters)
- `@mydomain\.com$` rest of your mail address and end of string.

notice also the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` - when you know you don't care about case, it makes letter groups a bit more readable

the error you made in your regex was adding the quantifier for your *complete* capture group - meaning a repetition of 6-30 times of the whole group.

i also recommend https://regex101.com/ for all your regex needs

Comment: You can, optionally, turn case-sensitivity on or off inside the expression using (?i)  and (?-i) respectively. @"(?i)^[a-z][a-z0-9.]{4,28}[a-z]@mydomain\.com$"

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option:

```
^(?![0-9.]|.*[0-9.]@)[a-zA-Z0-9.]{6,30}@mydomain\.com$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xZHfyG/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?![0-9.]|.*[0-9.]@)` - Negative lookahead to prevent start with dot/digit or end dot/digit before the "@".
- `[a-zA-Z0-9.]{6,30}` - 6-30 Characters specified in class.
- `@mydomain\.com` - Literally match "@mydomain.com". Notice the backslash before the dot to make it literal (outside a character class).
- `$` - End line anchor.

I was going to mention a case-insensitive alternative, but it looks like @FranzGleichmann got you [covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66730266/9758194) =)

Comment: nice lookaround, never really got my brain around them. but i got you beat performance-wise ;)

Comment: No doubt about that!

Comment: I think you can gain a bit more "performance" by using a negated character class excluding matching an `@` in the lookahead `^(?![0-9.]|[^\s@]*[0-9.]@)`